# Group by Country with bridge table

Tags: sql, database

I am not quite sure with the tables below to write a query that returns countries that have communities.  The `CommunityLocation` bridge table is where I can look for companies and their locations but not quite sure how to really mold this query.

```
Community
  community_id

Location
  location_id
  country_id

Country
  country_id

CommunityLocation
  community_id
  location_id
```

So I just need a list of country IDs that have communities.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
select distinct
   c.country_id 
from 
   countires c
join Location l
   on c.country_id = l.country_id
join CommunityLocation cl
   on cl.location_id = l.location_id
```

Comment: close I think I need a group by in here too.  I added `group by c.country_id` and it works.  Thank you!

Comment: isn't group by what you need, not distinct?

Comment: @PositiveGuy does it matter , they will do the same thing ( in this solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
select c.country_id 
from countries c
where exists (select 1
              from Location l join
                   CommunityLocation cl
                   on cl.location_id = l.location_id
              where c.country_id = l.country_id
             );
```

This avoids extra processing for removing duplicates -- and that is usually a performance gain.